# message count from member in the entire server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im trying to make a command to count the message count from the member in the server and not a certain channel

````
@bot.tree.command(name="message_count", description = "see members message count in the server")
async def message_count(ctx:discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    counter = 0
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit = 100):
            if message.author == member:
                counter += 1

    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has sent **{counter}** messages in this server.')
[error][1]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJkjB.png
````

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ctx.guild.channels` is handing you the `CategoryChannels`, in other words the "groups" of channels.

What you want are the `TextChannels`, which can be obtained by replacing `ctx.guild.channels` by `ctx.guild.text_channels`.

Comment: [Unknown interaction](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1044056386373431416/1133102283102625902/image.png)

Comment: `
@bot.tree.command(name="message_count", description = "see members message count in the server")
async def message_count(ctx:discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
    counter = 0
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit = 100):
            if message.author == member:
                counter += 1

    await ctx.response.send_message(f'{member.mention} has sent **{counter}** messages in this server.')
`
@Clement Genninasca

Comment: That's another issue, the code taking too long probably. If you use limit = 10 it works,  right? Just defer the response